# Is $|\sin(x\pi)|$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ one of the correct examples of a continuous function which is not differentiable only at integers?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

If we observe the nature of the function $|\sin(x\pi)|$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then this function is continuous everywhere but not differentiable only at $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ (integers). Is my observation correct?

Comment: Yes. There are many other functions with this property.

Comment: There are a lot of periodic functions that also satisfy this. If $f:\mathbb [0,1)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then $f(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$ usually satisfies the condition. (Occasionally, you might end up with a completely continuous function)